# Underscore at the beginning of a variable name in ms access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to add an initial underscore to a variable name like `_user` in VBA in ms access, but it is showing error as soon as the cursor is leaving that line. Please look at the error :

[image]

Can anybody tell me the reason and help me to do so?

Comment: Google works well:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/visual-basic-naming-rules  "...You must use a letter as the first character."

Comment: Simply change it like this - `Dim a_size As String`.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn - The link you provided with the help of Google is for .Net, but i am having problem in VBA.

Comment: Yes, the link WAS .Net... but look at the updated comment because I changed it to show VBA (it's illegal in VBA and .Net).  You can't use an underscore as the first character

Comment: Got the answer now! But it's not illegal in .Net though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @Wayne in the comments, it is not allowed to start the naming with an underscore: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/visual-basic-naming-rules

I guess that the reason for this is that the `_` is a special sign, that is used for initialization of Events in VBA. Thus, it is already taken.

A better guess - in VBA the underscore is used for line separator as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8515496/5448626